# <asp:UpdatePanel > doesn't work inside a table <tr>?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have a problem getting an `<asp:UpdatePanel..>` to work inside a `<table>.. <tr> </tr>` structure and I don't know why. When the UpdatePanel is commented out everything works fine, but when I un-comment the UpdatePanel the contents of the `<tr> </tr>` tag doesn't even show up in Visual Studio 2010. This content does display when I run the web page but the UpdatePanel doesn't work. Non of my other web pages in this project have this problem but, then again, I use `<div>`s instead of `<table`>s in them.
One other thing. The  is in my MasterPage. 
Here is my script:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="W9UpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="6">
            <div class="branchSetupSectionTitle">W-9 Information:</div>
          </td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
           <td colspan="2">
             <asp:Button ID="btnDownloadW9Pdf" runat="server" 
             Text="Download W-9"  onclick="btnDownloadW9Pdf_Click" AutoPostBack="True" /> 
             <%--<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator24" 
              runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtFirstPaymentAmount" Display="Dynamic" 
              ErrorMessage="The dollar amount you entered is in the wrong format." 
              ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="^\d+(\.\d\d)?$">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>--%>
              <asp:CheckBox ID="chkW9FormSubmitted" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
              oncheckedchanged="chkW9FormSubmitted_CheckedChanged" 
              Text=" I have submitted this W-9 Form" />
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
         </tr> 
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

   </tr>
```

The event fires for both the button and the checkbox but the entire page is refreshed.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: steveekershaw have you tried formatting the code inside your project..? what's the code look like above the last </tr> looks like you have some formatting issues going on there can't tell unless you show the full aspx code also why do you have that type of code in your master page..? shouldn't that code be in one of the Aspx pages that inherits from MasterPage..?

Comment: [Should questions include tags in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles#_=_) - no, they should not.

Comment: @Brian in this case its ok to have it, see this line `Can I use jQuery to foo the bar on the baz, or am I stuck using plain JavaScript?`. besides none of the things he mentioned are tagged in his question.

Comment: @AbZy - Point taken :)

Comment: Have you looked at the resultant HTML? I seem to recall that UpdatePanel renders to a div, and that might be the problem.

Answer (score 5):

UpdatePanel needs to render a div or span in order to function correctly. Since neither of these elements can be rendered between table rows, UpdatePanel does not have a placeholder to render the postback response html, and thus it doesn't work.

A workaround in your case may be to see which part of your page does not need to be inside the update panel and leave it outside. You could leave just the contents of `<td colspan="2">` inside the UpdatePanel.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scm" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<fieldset>
<legend>Truck Master Entry Form</legend>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upd1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
                    <td align="right">
                        Truck no :
                    </td>
                    <td align="left">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="truckno" runat="server" Width="120px" Height="20px" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">
                        Size :
                    </td>
                    <td align="left">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="drptrucksize" runat="server" Width="120px" Height="20px" DataValueField="WEIGHT"
                            DataTextField="SIZE" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drptrucksize_SelectedIndexChanged"
                            AutoPostBack="true" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">
                        Type :
                    </td>
                    <td align="left">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txttrucktype" runat="server" Width="120px" Height="20px" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">
                        Weight :
                    </td>
                    <td align="left">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtweight" runat="server" Width="120px" Height="20px" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td align="left">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnsave" runat="server" Text="Save" Width="100px" Height="50px" />
                        <asp:Button ID="btncancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" Width="100px" Height="50px" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: explain what you changed.

Comment: Either put your whole table inside the UpdatePanel, or set your UpdatePanel in a table cell. Also pay attention to what is being rendered inside the UpdatePanel - I had a ASP NET PlaceHolder that had some unclosed html tags that provoked nasty, unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

The update panel need to be put outside the table. Look at

Mohammad Shahnawaz's code.